# Adding a popup window with PHP Smarty Framework

Tags: php, smarty

I have a website built on PHP Smarty framework and I need to add another popup window when site opens for the first time. The site already has one.

Index file is like this:

```
include_once(__DIR__ . '/_config/init.php');

if (!$_SESSION['visited']) {
    $tpl->assign("POPUP",1);
    $_SESSION['visited'] = 1;
}
$tpl->assign("POPUP",1);
$tpl->display('index.html');
```

This displays a popup window that is written in file "templates/pop-up.html"

How can I add another popup window just in front of this one?

I'm thinking to write another file for the second popup window, "templates/pop-up-2.html" and have a line such as `$tpl->assign("POPUP",2);`. Would this work ? but how can I link the file and the function parameter in Smarty framework ?

Comment: These GDPR notifications are really getting out of hand :) You tried anything, like `$tpl2->display('some other url);`?

Comment: I did not, im totally clueless with Smarty. I thought `$tpl->assign("POPUP",1);` holds the key, that I could define `$tpl->assign("POPUP",2);` as another popup

Comment: My guess is `1` is actually a Booelan true there. Those might just be flags passed to the template. Might be some code in said template that evaluates the passed flag and decides to fire the JS which likely actually loads the popup... So popup = true. Look in the template for reference to `POPUP` variable.

Comment: Thats an interesting part that searching through entire project POPUP case-sensitive is only found in index.php file.